# Command must be inputted within 3 seconds [python]

Tags: python, time

I am creating a text adventure in python and i want it to be different than the traditional turn-based gameplay. But also not the real time gameplay of a MUD. 
I have designed a method where the program asks you to input a certain string within a certain amount of seconds. 
E.g.

```
while goblin != str('dead'):
    type 'slash at goblin' within 3 seconds.
    if you succeed the program prints "you slash at the goblin, the goblin is now dead"
    goblin == str('dead')
    if you fail the program prints "the goblin slashes at you (-5 hp)."
    hp == int(hp) - 5
    and restarts the loop.
```

any ideas on how i could do this?
how to force the program to type a command within a certain amount seconds?
any help would be much appreciated THnx!

Comment: Maybe you could adapt this [Retry Loop](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578527-retry-loop/?in=lang-python) recipe on ActiveState,